# How to open and read an excel file from Oracle Forms in the READ ONLY mode?

Tags: excel, oracle, ole, oracleforms

I have the following piece of code to read the Excel Files. But recently, my user has put a password on the excel file. Therefore, when I try to read the file, a message is poped-up and ask to enter the password to open the excel in the edit more, or just open it in the Read Only mode.

I just need to read the data. Then I just want to open it in the read only mode without having the pop-up.

Do you have any idea how can I solve this?

> ```
>   ----------------Get the file to open        ---------------------------
> ```

```
v_fName := :upload.ti_file_name_upload;

 clear_form ( no_validate );

    --------------INITIATE EXCEL APPLICATION---------------------------

application := client_OLE2.create_obj('Excel.Application'); 
client_OLE2.set_property(application,'Visible', 'false');

----------------GET WORKBOOKS FROM EXCEL APPLICATION---------------

    workbooks := client_OLE2.Get_Obj_Property(application, 'Workbooks');

    ----------------OPEN REQUIRED WORKBOOK-----------------------------

    args := client_OLE2.CREATE_ARGLIST;
    client_OLE2.add_arg(args,v_fName); 
    workbook := client_OLE2.GET_OBJ_PROPERTY(workbooks,'Open',args);
    client_OLE2.destroy_arglist(args);

----------------OPEN REQUIRED WORKSHEET----------------------------

    args:= client_OLE2.create_arglist; 
    client_OLE2.add_arg(args, 'HC');   
    worksheet := client_OLE2.GET_OBJ_PROPERTY(workbook, 'Sheets', args);
    client_OLE2.destroy_arglist(args);          

----------------Specify columns that must be read------------------
```

and rest of the code ....

Thank you!
M

Answer (score 0):

There is no such arguments in client_ole2 package, what you can do is after getting the file name with path (v_fName := :upload.ti_file_name_upload;), copy and paste as read only with different name and then open it using client_ole2.